# How to delay all keyframes to make space for a new animation scene?

Tags: animation

I have made an animation, but I have now decided that I want to have another scene in the middle of the animation.

Is there a way to delay ALL keyframes and make space for the new scene without breaking the animation?

Comment: hello, maybe give more information, do you have several objects that are animated? do you use the NLA? etc...

Comment: Yes, I have several rigs that are animated, and had their textures keyframed as well. I don't use NLA.

Comment: you could push all the keyframes but it may cause problems for some animations that are not displayed in the Dope Sheet?

Answer (score 1):

To solve your problem, you can select all (animated) objects in your scene, then select all keyframes that you want to move, and hit G to translate them further ahead.

To prevent this problem in the future, I suggest splitting your animation into shorter sequences, but this is case specific, not useable for when you want to extend the scene.

Since I don't know what exactly is going on there, I can only suggest.